# How to resolve module dependency using code in atg(Without Modifying META-INF)?

Tags: java, atg

How to resolve module dependency using code in atg(Without Modifying META-INF)?
Already half of the project work is done, now we can not change the META-INF
So can you guys please advice me how I can get the top level module things to bottom level module?

Comment: If it is only half done... you can still half change it... The MANIFEST.MF is a coding asset, just like your property and java files. You should change it.

Comment: if you can provide more details as to what exactly you are trying to do, I might be of some help. you can explicitly put properties files in localconfig but might not serve your purpose fully. More details of what you are doing and what you have tried can help us in answering better.

Answer (score 0):

The module structure of an ATG instance is determined at launch time. It cannot be changed at runtime or programmatically from within the application.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can use a build system - maven, ant, gradle, whatever, and their framework of custom plugins or tasks - to determine and affect what gets built at compile time or assembly time, or you can use some scripting - shell scripting on Unix or batch files on Windows - to determine and affect what gets included at startup when launching an instance.